# Why can't I make an exact copy of a Google Sheets project that uses importrange?

Tags: google-sheets, copy, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, importrange

I shared a Google sheet to another user. The other user is able to open it, but when they go to make a copy everything comes up as "value" even on the original user's sheets.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the copy of the sheet is not linked with the referenced sheet in **`IMPORTRANGE`**. Every time you use **`IMPORTRANGE`** you need to authorize the link between those two given sheets. without that authorization, you got errors as you mentioned.

To resolve this you have two options:

- if the referenced sheet is public you just need to run simple **`IMPORTRANGE`** in any cell and authorize the connection between the referenced sheet and copy of the sheet. you will get **`#REF!`** error on which you need to hover mouse cursor and a magic button will pop up

  ```
  =IMPORTRANGE("ID-OR-URL", "Sheet1!A1:A10")
  ```
- if the referenced sheet is private, you need to ask the original owner for permission and authorize it as mentioned above

---

## UPDATE:

```
=QUERY({
 IMPORTRANGE("1X_NBWq1m9iBxvYXhy2wcttHanvPFPlAOJWgbbKbJimQ","January!A:Z");
 IMPORTRANGE("1X_NBWq1m9iBxvYXhy2wcttHanvPFPlAOJWgbbKbJimQ","February!A:Z");
 IMPORTRANGE("1X_NBWq1m9iBxvYXhy2wcttHanvPFPlAOJWgbbKbJimQ","March!A:Z"); 
 IMPORTRANGE("1X_NBWq1m9iBxvYXhy2wcttHanvPFPlAOJWgbbKbJimQ","April!A:Z");
 IMPORTRANGE("1X_NBWq1m9iBxvYXhy2wcttHanvPFPlAOJWgbbKbJimQ","May!A:Z");
 IMPORTRANGE("1X_NBWq1m9iBxvYXhy2wcttHanvPFPlAOJWgbbKbJimQ","June!A:Z"); 
 IMPORTRANGE("1X_NBWq1m9iBxvYXhy2wcttHanvPFPlAOJWgbbKbJimQ","July!A:Z");
 IMPORTRANGE("1X_NBWq1m9iBxvYXhy2wcttHanvPFPlAOJWgbbKbJimQ","August!A:Z");
 IMPORTRANGE("1X_NBWq1m9iBxvYXhy2wcttHanvPFPlAOJWgbbKbJimQ","September!A:Z"); 
 IMPORTRANGE("1X_NBWq1m9iBxvYXhy2wcttHanvPFPlAOJWgbbKbJimQ","October!A:Z");
 IMPORTRANGE("1X_NBWq1m9iBxvYXhy2wcttHanvPFPlAOJWgbbKbJimQ","November!A:Z");
 IMPORTRANGE("1X_NBWq1m9iBxvYXhy2wcttHanvPFPlAOJWgbbKbJimQ","December!A:Z")}, 
 "where Col3 = 'Bob' 
    and Col1 is not null")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I am getting a value error. It says: Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col3. But there is a Col3. It works on the original

Comment: Cannot share the sheet. Heres the code if that would help: =QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","January!A:Z"); IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","February!A:Z"); IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","March!A:Z"); IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","April!A:Z"); IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","May!A:Z"); IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","June!A:Z"); IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","July!A:Z"); IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","August!A:Z"); IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","September!A:Z"); IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","October!A:Z"); IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","November!A:Z"); IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","December!A:Z")}, "select * where Col3 = 'Rose' and Col1 is not null")

Comment: Yes. All the same

Comment: I am again getting a value error when copying and pasting the formula to a new workbook, it says, Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col3. But there is a Col3.

Comment: =QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","January!A:Z"); IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","February!A:Z"); IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","March!A:Z"); IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","April!A:Z"); IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","May!A:Z"); IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","June!A:Z"); IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","July!A:Z"); IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","August!A:Z"); IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","September!A:Z"); IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","October!A:Z"); IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","November!A:Z"); IMPORTRANGE("SHEET ID","December!A:Z")}, "select * where Col3 = 'Rose' and Col1 is not null")

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17LuL3vETnqjcXMw5GV3UUXJmUlPh8Wzscd_rdy_-u54/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X_NBWq1m9iBxvYXhy2wcttHanvPFPlAOJWgbbKbJimQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: hard to tell without further knowledge of your new sheet. try to replace all commas with semicolons

Comment: That did not work, how did you get the other spreadsheet provided to work. Thank you for your help!

Comment: all I did was add single quotes around Bob -> 'Bob'

Comment: It has something to do with the sharing settings, I have to only share the data with certain people. However, the importrange is than you to use a selection of the data that do not have access to all data. Any work around?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you requesting some particular columns before you give access to the new spreadsheet.

Simply go to any other empty cell (i.e. the cell under that one you mentioned above.)
Write a simple `IMPORTRANGE` function like this:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1X_NBWq1m9iBxvYXhy2wcttHanvPFPlAOJWgbbKbJimQ","January!A:Z")
```

Then click again the cell you just filled andclick "Allow Access".

After access allowed empty the cell you just created and you will propably be able to get the first cell formula working.